# iTunes Connect payment made on a closed account

Tags: app-store-connect

My iTunes connect is linked to an old account that closed on September 4 or 5, so I have no more access to it to check if the payment has been made on it.

I changed bank so I updated my banking infos in iTunes Connect in order to receive the next payments on my new banking account and received a mail on **August 30, 2017** that saying my banking infos has been processed. But when I go to the **Payments and Financial reports** part in iTunes Connect for July, it is marked that the payment was made on September 7 on my old account, not the new one.

Will I receive an email from Apple saying that my payment has been refused and reported on the next month or something like that, or should I contact my old bank ?

Comment: Seems like you should contact Apple.

Comment: Yes that's what I did, I just want to know if someone has already be in this situation, because it is a rather urgent problem

Comment: Gotcha. Not sure what the right approach is then.

Answer (score 1):

If the charge was declined by your old bank, you'll get a message stating that there was a billing issue and it will ask you to update your billing info to correct the issue.

Theres more info and and an explanation on how to resolve the billing issue at 
[this page.](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT203005)

If you didn't receive a message like that, I would suggest checking your current account to see if that charge appeared on it. If not I would recommend contacting Apple or your old bank.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Matt121, the problem is that the payment appears done on iTunes Connect. And the link you gave me is for iTunes Store banking infos, not iTunes Connect

Answer (score 0):

Contact both the bank and open a ticket on iTunes Connect with Apple Developer Support and request the billing department be made aware of the change.

- http://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/contactus/

They both will either offer a way to assist you to get the cash sooner than next month or if that’s not feasible - ensure that next month is set.

A bit of a bummer, but if the payment is less than about $10k US - you’ll likely have to just wait as opposed to getting someone to facilitate a quicker solution. If the amount is more than $10k have your accountant or lawyer reach out to Apple or get them an accounting role AppleID so they can contact Apple directly to facilitate a solution for payment.